# Retrieving Input Values from a Text Box

Tags: javascript

I need to make a box so that when the user enters a value of one through 6, it rolls that many dice. I'm a complete beginner to javascript and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my function:

```
function NumberValue() {
        for (i = 0; i <['randNumber']; i++){
            var numberRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
            var userNumber = '../images/die' + numberRoll + '.gif';
            myNewTag = "<img id='dieImgRandom' src='" + userNumber + "'>"
            document.getElementById('dieDivRandom').innerHTML += myNewTag;
```

And here is my body element:

```
<h1>Why don't you pick please?</h1>

<div id="dieDivRandom" style="text-align:center">

<p>

<div id="dieImageRand">

<img id="dieImgRandom" alt="die image" src="../images/die1.gif">

<br>

<input type="text" id="randNumber" size=20 value="Enter 1 through 6">

<input type="button" value="Click to Roll" onclick="NumberValue();">

</div>
```

The function needs to allow a user to submit the number one, two, three, four, five, or six, and that many images need to display on the screen. The images a relocated in my images folder, so relative links will work just fine. That's actually what I need to use. Thank you.

Comment: `document.getElementById('randNumber').value`

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
for (i = 0; i <['randNumber']; i++){
```

With:

```
for (i = 0; i <document.getElementById('randNumber').value; i++) {
```

---

The `<input />` tag can be accessed by using either of the following:

1. `document.getElementById('inputId').value;`
2. `document.formName.inputName.value`

---

Finally, your code becomes:

```
function NumberValue() {
    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById('inputId').value; i++) {
        var numberRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        var userNumber = '../images/die' + numberRoll + '.gif';
        myNewTag = "<img id='dieImgRandom' src='" + userNumber + "'>"
        document.getElementById('dieDivRandom').innerHTML += myNewTag;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, but now it rolls only one die regardless of the number that you put in. I tried all 1,2,3,4,5,6, and it only rolled one die. Any ideas how to make it so that when you enter, for example, 5 it rolls 5 die?

Comment: I don't get you! Like what?

Answer (score 0):

Use this   to read values from textbox

```
function NumberValue() {     
var ranNum = document.getElementById('randNumber').value;

        for (i = 0; i <ranNum ; i++){

        }

}
```

EDIT:

If you want to validate the Entered number

add this block of code

```
function NumberValue() {     
var ranNum = document.getElementById('randNumber').value;
        if(ranNum < 1 || ranNum > 6) {
           alert("Please enter number from 1 to 6 only");
           return false;
          }

        for (i = 0; i <ranNum ; i++){

        }

        return true;

}
```

Comment: Okay, now It works, but I need to limit it so that the user can only put in 1 through 6. Any ideas?